# What are the best icons for cancel, delete and close?

Tags: icons

What's best icon for cancel, delete and close? 
(i want define 1 icon per situation in my application)

1. [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVDr5.png]
2. [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GS0AN.png]

   - i found 1,2 is cancel action what's different between 1,2? / or \ is right?
3. [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uw5Aa.png]
4. [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjK9w.gif]
5. [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EUkb.png]
6. [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjOR9.png]

I have screen shot for use delete and cancel edit action
[image]

Comment: This is a graphic design question really as there's no other context or use case information provided in order to say whether one is more suitable for your situation than another, but I'd go for number 5 out of those options.

Comment: To clarify - you want one common icon to act for all three situations - cancel + delete + close?

Comment: Without knowing the context of the action and the interface you are using it on it is not possible to give you a qualified answer. Can you post some screenshots?

Comment: @3iscuit Welcome to UX Stack Exchange. To reply to someone, put an @ before their name at the beginning of your comment. That way they'll be notified of the reply.

Comment: As Katie said, we can't give you useful answers without more context. Can you elaborate on what you mean by "what's different between 1,2? / or \"? Our [FAQ](http://ux.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) also has advice on what makes a good question. Because it's not really answerable in its current form, I'm closing the question for now. If you decide to make improvements, let me know with an @ reply and we'll consider re-opening it.

Comment: Id love to answer this.  I clicked re-open.  The circle with the slash through it generally means "restricted" or "not allowed".  I find the circles with horizontal dash to be confusing because it often means open/close, not delete.  5 and 6 are much more universal, although depending on the situation you might use gray rather than red.  Red is generally meaning "destroy" and harsh.  A gray x might feel softer.  User Experience includes graphic design, so this question is perfectly rational to me.

Comment: @Patrick McElhaney may be my screenshot can make clearer question. What is best icon for this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all depends on situation...

1, 2 — "No", "cancel"
4 — "Stop", may be used in alerts
5, 6 — "Delete", "cancel" if placed near some action, or "close" if placed on top corner of ui element.

Also minus icon is great for remove action.

Comment: He wants *one common icon* for *all* actions...

Comment: Yes - one common icon for all three was my interpretation of the bit in square brackets, but I might be wrong - its not *that* clear from the English. I'll ask to make sure.

Comment: What's different between 1,2?

Answer (score 6):

That's actually a question for google:

-> [Delete](http://www.google.com/search?q=delete&um=1&hl=en&biw=1124&bih=716&tbm=isch&source=lnt&tbs=isz%3ai&sa=X&ei=kLkvTqSAKtGLswbiptkn&ved=0CAwQpwUoAw)

-> [Cancel](http://www.google.com/search?um=1&hl=en&biw=1124&bih=716&tbs=isz%3ai&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=cancel&oq=cancel&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=83472l84048l0l84295l6l5l0l0l0l0l155l586l1.4l5)

-> [Close](http://www.google.com/search?um=1&hl=en&biw=1124&bih=716&tbs=isz%3ai&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=close&oq=close&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=26861l27318l0l27843l5l4l0l0l0l0l135l438l2.2l4)

As you can see from the results, there is no real difference between the icons used for these actions (except maybe the trash can for delete).

**Solution: Always use text with the icon** (or use text only). The only exception I can think of is when the action is obvious from the context (like the close button on the top right or left of a window/dialog).

Hope that helps, Phil

Comment: why we use icon and text? Is it duplicate?

Comment: @3iscuit: Not many icons are understood by all users and usually don't enhance usability. I'd recommend to read this: http://uxmyths.com/post/715009009/myth-icons-enhance-usability

Comment: And to the person who downvoted: A comment would be appreciated.

Comment: Old, but just had same issue, so DELETE = TRASH / BIN, CLOSE or CANCEL = X or circle striked through.